# iframe loading from resource file

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon

I am creating a Firefox extension and trying to load an iframe with the following characteristic.

`<iframe src="resource://html/iframe_src.html"></iframe>`

The permissions are set so that `resource://html/iframe_src.html` displays the correct content.  I don't know why the iframe refuses to load.  Could it be a same origin policy problem?

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL of the document containing the <iframe> snippet? chrome:// should be able to load things from resource:///, while http:// and file:// should not.

If the load is denied by the same origin policy, you should see a message like this in the Error Console:

> Security Error: Content at file:///... may not load or link to resource:///...